# use NullWritable as OutputKeyClass, but i didnt get the expected result

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

i just want to output the value, so i use NullWritable as OutputKeyClass, like this:

```
protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values,
            Reducer<Text, Text, NullWritable, Text>.Context context)
                    throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        for(Text value : values){
            context.write(NullWritable.get(), value);
        }
    }
```

and I set job like this:

```
job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(baseInPath));
    FileSystem.get(conf).delete(new Path(baseOutPath), true);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(baseOutPath));

    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
```

But when I check the result path, I got this.
�LZO

`    @��V��/�!�Z0|res|1*"|33260580217607|2|1|0.2|23|2016-03-28 13:57:42
0|pay 6-03-28 13:57:42

the string start with 0|res|1…… is value, but there are some garbled at front.
 i think they are the pointer of NullWritable.
How can i remove these garbled? Is my code right?

Comment: Have you enabled any map output compression codec?

Comment: Job job = new Job(conf, "shop_re_pay");
  job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
  job.setJarByClass(ShopRepayJob.class);
  job.setMapperClass(FailPayMap.class);
  job.setReducerClass(FailPayReduce.class);
  job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
  job.setOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
  job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
  job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
  job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
  FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(baseInPath));
  FileSystem.get(conf).delete(new Path(baseOutPath), true);
  FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(baseOutPath));

Comment: this is full job config.

Comment: i didn't config the compression codec.

Comment: There s nothing wrong in the code. May be you could post your complete code with some sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the output it seems LZO compression is set. You can try having a look at your mapred-site.xml and to see if this property is set

```xml
<property>
  <name>mapred.map.output.compression.codec</name>
  <value>com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec</value>
</property>
```

For more details : [link](http://xiaming.me/posts/2014/05/03/enable-lzo-compression-on-hadoop-pig-and-spark/)

Comment: oh, yes.I asked our hadoop manager and they give me a method to decpmpress data. thanks